# build error trying to add Firebase to iOS app, "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp""

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to add Firebase analytic support to an existing iOS app.
The app was already using CocoaPods to import FMDB, and also has a manual build dependency on TensorFlow C library.

After adding Firebase to my podfile file my build failed with,
"Module 'Firebase' not found"

Podfile

```
target 'myapp' do
  pod 'FMDB'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  
end
```

Header Search Paths

```
$(TENSORFLOW_ROOT) $(TENSORFLOW_ROOT)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads $(TENSORFLOW_ROOT)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen $(TENSORFLOW_ROOT)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/protobuf/src $(TENSORFLOW_ROOT)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/proto $(TENSORFLOW_ROOT)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/nsync/public/ $(TENSORFLOW_ROOT)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/absl ${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/**
```

Framework Search Paths

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks" "${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseAnalytics" "${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleAppMeasurement"
```

Library Search Paths

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks" "${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseAnalytics" "${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleAppMeasurement"
```

Other Linker Paths

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks" "${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseAnalytics" "${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleAppMeasurement"
```

## Attempt 2

This seems to be fixed by adding $(inherited) to the "Header Search Paths" and "Framework Search Paths", as if these paths are customized they don't seem to pick up the pods without this. Although FMDB was working fine without this.
But this still failed with a later build error,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

If I remove the reference to FIRApp in my code, it builds fine.

## Attempt 3

Build settings

Add $(inherited) to "Other Linker Flags"
This gives a build error on FMDB now,

```
ld: library not found for -lFMDB
```

## Attempt 4

Build settings

Add $(inherited) to "Library Search Paths"
This gives a different build error in FMDB

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FMResultSet._parentDB' in:
    /Users/paphus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Miami-btsjnxdkshhzzmcximegwcbjweif/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Miami.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Miami.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FMResultSet-8b2ff65f24dc1207099e1a3d8676b2cd074aac777d9679e86442f90b5f7cd476.o
    /Users/paphus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Miami-btsjnxdkshhzzmcximegwcbjweif/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FMDB/libFMDB.a(FMResultSet.o)
ld: 49 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

## Attempt 5

Build Phase

Link Binary with Library,
Seems to be missing FirebaseCore now?

```
ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore
```

I also tried "pod deintegrate" and pod cache clean" and a few other things, no luck.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in new blank project? If not, clean up environment: close Xcode, remove directories myapp/Pods, ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*, ~/.cocoapods/*. Use latest cocoapods. Run with pod --verbose install. Build in Xocde, and check compilation flags (search paths) in build logs.

Comment: In addition to @paiv's suggestions, after running `pod deintegrate`, manually scrub all Pods references from header and library settings before rerunning `pod install`

Comment: Do you have somewhere example project where it fails with this error?

Comment: I have tried scrub all of the pods, it does not change any of the errors

Comment: @James Can you please try removing -ObjC from Other Linker Flags once if added?

Comment: Are you able to build https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/analytics? If so, you could binary search the difference in settings to isolate the problem.

Comment: removing -ObjC does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I gave up on getting the pod to work and instead followed,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

downloaded SDK from,
https://firebase.google.com/download/ios

This was way way easier and simple to setup and worked the first time.
Just added the FirebaseAnalytics directory to the project as a group and added the Firebase.h file to the project, that's it. Works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting OTHER_LDFLAGS build settings to $(inherited) flag?